# What is the correct way to populate an uncontrolled react input field?

Tags: reactjs

`defaultValue` only works for the first time the page is loaded. When loading the same page again, but with different `props`, the uncontrolled input fields do not get populated with new values from the new `props`. It seems there is no way to set value for an uncontrolled input field in react?

I'm using Material-UI, my uncontrolled input field looks something like this:

```
<TextField
  ref={input => this.dataNode.Name = input}
  defaultValue={this.props.dataNode.Name}
  floatingLabelText="Name"
/>
```

It seems adding a random `key` to the input does the trick, however, do I really need to introduce a random key for each uncontrolled input?

```
<TextField
  key={some_random_thing}
  ref={input => this.dataNode.Name = input}
  defaultValue={this.props.dataNode.Name}
  floatingLabelText="Name"
/>
```

Comment: some of your code may be useful :)

Comment: could you explain this: `When loading the same page again` ?? how u r doing this? because if update the values in the parent component, child will definitely get updated.

Comment: Think about the navigation menu. All menu items link to the same page, but with different `props` passed in. In my case, if I click another link to another page, and come back to the form, the value got correctly populated, however, if I navigate to the same page, even if with new `props`, the form still has the old values.

Comment: Maybe I should not say page, let's say, component.

Comment: In case of controlled (using `value` instead of `defaultValue`) input, there's no such problem. However, I need to use uncontrolled input in my case.

Comment: Adding a `key` property to the `TextField` seems to work, but do I really need to write another random key generator for each field?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved (worked around) by adding `key={Math.random()}`:

```
<TextField
  key={Math.random()}
  ref={input => this.dataNode.Name = input}
  defaultValue={this.props.dataNode.Name}
  floatingLabelText="Name"
/>
```

Ugly!

Answer (score 0):

By the very fact that you are "setting the input" you are trying to "control" the input field.  I would just go ahead and go through the extra few lines of code to make this a controlled input.  There is no harm in that, and it's actually what I think you are trying to do in the "react" way of thinking.

Comment: No, we are talking about an uncontrolled input. I understand how controlled input works. But my question is about an uncontrolled input.

Comment: What I am saying is that by setting the value at all, you are applying some level of control on the input no?

Comment: Did you mean using `value` instead of `defaultValue`? If this is the case, the input becomes readonly.